# Unable to Parse JSON In my application

Tags: android

I've been trying to figure this out for the past 4 days and I am about to pull my hair out!

I need your help, can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Here is the JSON format link I am using for development: REMOVED FOR PRIVACY CONCERNS

Here is my code:

```
 public class JSONActivity extends Activity {


TextView http;
HttpClient client;
JSONObject json;


final static String URL = "REMOVED FOR PRIVACY CONCERNS

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    http = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.http);
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    new Read().execute("firstName");


}

public JSONObject getpw(String password)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
    url.append(password);

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
    int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (status == 200) {
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
        JSONArray getname = new JSONArray(data);
        JSONObject last = getname.getJSONObject(3);
        return last;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(JSONActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        return null;
    }
}
public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        try {
            json=getpw("trustme");
            return json.getString(arg0[0]);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        http.setText(result);
    }

}}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be of very great help to describe what your problem is...

Comment: My problem is, the application fails to retrieve "firstName" and I can see there is some data exchange going on, but my app doesnt display anything in the end.

Comment: Put logs into your app to see whats going on. You should have a more specific problem than "it doesn't work" `Log.d("YourTag" , "Test hit this line");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting a JSONArray back, but the webservice is just returning a JSONObject.

I made the following changes:

`JSONArray getname = new JSONArray(data);` --> `JSONObject getname = new JSONObject(data);`

and in the Async Task, I made the following change:

`return json.getString("firstName");`

Here's the complete code:

```
public class PlaygroundActivity extends Activity {
    TextView http;
    HttpClient client;
    JSONObject json;

    final static String URL = "REMOVED FOR PRIVACY CONCERNS

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        http = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.http);
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        new Read().execute("firstName");

    }

    public JSONObject getpw(String password) throws ClientProtocolException,
            IOException, JSONException {
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
        url.append(password);

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
        HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
        int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (status == 200) {
            HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
            JSONObject getname = new JSONObject(data);

            return getname;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(PlaygroundActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                json = getpw("trustme");
                return json.getString("firstName");
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            http.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: QuinnVT, Thank you! its working fine! I couldnt have done it without your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to get response from server and then parse json.

```
public static void extractParameters(){
    String urlRequest = "REMOVED FOR PRIVACY CONCERNS";
    String response = getServerResponse(urlRequest);
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        boolean suspended = json.getBoolean("suspended");
        String firstName = json.getString("firstName");
        String lastName = json.getString("lastName");
        int checkdin = json.getInt("checkedin");
        int checkindatetime = json.getInt("checkindatetime");
        //Get Json object address
        JSONObject address = json.getJSONObject("address");
        String streedAddress = address.getString("streetAddress");//In same way get city etc
        //Get PhoneNumber Array
        JSONArray phoneNumbers = json.getJSONArray("phoneNumber");
        String type = phoneNumbers.getJSONObject(0).getString("type");
        String number = phoneNumbers.getJSONObject(0).getString("number");// and so on for 1,2,3...


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}
```

These methods will help to get response from server

```
/**
 * 
 * @param urlRequest URL of server 
 * @return
 */
public static String getServerResponse(String urlRequest){
    Log.d("urlRequest",urlRequest);
    String response = "";
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlRequest).openConnection();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        response = read(conn.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d("response",response);
    return response.trim();
}
private static String read(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in), 1000);
    for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine()) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    in.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Example of JSON Response you sent is:

```
{
  "suspended": "false",
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "checkedin": 0,
  "checkindatetime": 0,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10021"
  },
  "phoneNumber": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "212 111-1111"
    },
    {
      "type": "fax",
      "number": "646 222-2222"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hey Muhammad, thank you VERY much for your response! I really do appreciate it. I will  give it a try now and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Muhammad, Can you please tell me how to parse the json after? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Would you be able to further assist me, Muhammad?